# Java 2D Int Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I dont quite understand what is the problem with the second declaration.

```
// Compiles fine
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

// error (Unexpected type, expected -reference ,found :int)
ArrayList<ArrayList<int>> intarray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<int>>();
```

Answer (score 3):

The way generics work is simple. The header of `List` looks a little like this:

```
public interface List<T>
```

Where `T` is some `Object`. However, `int` is not a subclass of `Object`. It is a primitive. So how do we get around this? We use `Integer`. `Integer` is the wrapper class for `int`. This allows us to use `int` values in a `List`, because when we add them, they get auto boxed into `Integer`.

Primitive types are actually scheduled for deprecation in Java 10. Taken from Wikipedia:

> There is speculation of removing primitive data types, as well as moving towards 64-bit addressable arrays to support large data sets somewhere around 2018.

**Just a Note on your Code**

In Java, the convention is to have the declaration using the *most generic type* and the definition using the *most specific concrete class*. For example:

```
List myList;
// List is the interface type. This is as generic as we can go realistically.

myList = new ArrayList();
// This is a specific, concrete type.
```

This means that if you want to use another type of `List`, you won't need to change much of your code. You can just swap out the implementation.

**Extra Reading**

- Read about [Wrapper Classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class).
- Read about [Auto Boxing and Unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).
- Read about [Primitive Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayList` is an implementation of `List<T>`, your problem is that you are trying to create an arraylist of int, its impossible since `int` is not an object. using `Integer` will solve your problem.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> intarray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only make List of Objects. int is a primitive type.

Try use:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> intarray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create an `ArrayList<Integer>` not an `ArrayList<int>`
A class(`Arraylist` in your case) can be a type of a CLASS (`Integer`)

Comment: Victor - Updated the question( was wrongly formateed)

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList does not except primitive types as an argument.  It only accepts Object types you should use:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> intArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```